# Silverlight 4 wait/spinner control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'd like to implement a spinner control ([something along these lines](http://www.southerntravelsindia.com/Images/wait_spinner.gif)) in Silverlight 4 to display during pending operations.  There are several examples on the web for Silverlight 3 but I'm either unable to compile them into my project or they just flat out display nothing.  In addition I'm unable to find any examples specific to Silverlight 4.

Can someone please post a sample for Silverlight 4 or a link to one?

Comment: Most of the examples should work from SL3...what are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good example of a spinner control [here](http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Silverlight-Loadinge-Spin-Icon-in-XAML.aspx).  It's very simple and may not be ideal but it works perfect for my purposes.  It's a XAML-only solution so it is very easy to port.

If you decide to use it, then I'd like to echo one of the commenters' suggestions that you change the `<Grid>` to a `<Viewbox>` so that the spinner will scale automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the BusyIndicator.

[How To Work With Silverlight BusyIndicator?](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightBusyIndicator.aspx)

[Custom Busyindicator style in Silverlight 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/busyindicator.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  The BusyIndicator is not adequate out of the box IMHO.  The Custom BusyIndicator example might work for me, but since it's not a packaged example (and I'm a Silverlight novice) I'm having a hard time getting all of the style info, etc ported over correctly to my project.  I'd still like to see a more portable example.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a pure xaml spinner out of another example I've found ( see source ). It works on silverlight 4 and moonlight 4 too.

[Pure XAML Spinner](https://github.com/inorton/XamlPreviewer/blob/master/XamlPreviewer/spinner.xaml)

Slightly nicer visual than the "rotate some rectangles" approach.